# Read a CSV File and create new csv and columns

Tags: python, csv

```
Mathew Jim    60
Gerry Hagger  61
Sam Page      23
Azli Muzan    52
David Agor    32
James Paine   40
Mike Gregor   63
Howard Jack   56
```

I have this data in CSV file with names and age in one column and would like a python script that will separate the names from the age, create a new CSV with the heights of the individuals classified as short, medium and tall.

```
Height  Classification
<5      short
5-6     medium
6>      tall
```

Will like two column headings of Names and Classification.

Comment: [This should help](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)

Comment: Word of advice, just don't classify people as this or that.
Especially when you will actually lose information.

Comment: FYI SO is not a code request service.  You have to do your research, work on it, hit a wall, research solutions to that wall, rinse and repeat.